# How to open file path within code comment in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some generated codes which contain comments like `// #line 56"/home/alan/quicker/painful/Worker.actor.cpp"`

Is it possible for vscode or any vscode extension to open the file path and jump to the corresponding line as described in this comment with just one simple mouse click?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in vscode only. But, if this link format is something common, you may be able to find an extension that does that. It can be easily achieved by implementing DocumentLinkProvider (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentLinkProvider%3CT%3E) like someone does here: https://github.com/ctf0/vscode-jump-to-line-number/tree/141504aba5fc2b88bf57e46e641284493249f5ce

Answer (score 2):

You can use an extension I made: [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links)

This tool allows you to extract file path and line/char positions and open the file there. The file links are in a separate view of the explorer bar.

If you also have relative paths make a second entry.

You can make global links but also scope them to a languageId. Here I have chosen `cpp`

```
"html-related-links.include": {
    "cpp": [
      {
        "find": "// #line (\d+)\"(/[^\"])\"",
        "filePath": "$2",
        "isAbsolutePath": true,
        "lineNr": "$1"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: man, I tried your setting, but it seems not working??? A simple Ctrl+Click wont open the file for me.

Comment: @SlowMohammud  look for the `Related Links` View in the Explorer Bar

Comment: you should disclose your affiliation. [/help/promotion](/help/promotion).