# May I link a relative path in some comments?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to show some help tips, and modify some files in config

Example

```
/**
 * Fix some issue
 *
 * @link file://$(workspaceFolder)/node_modules/xxxxxx/dist/index.cjs
 * Some tips
 */
```

Comment: what is the use of modifying the source files in `node_modules`, modify the original repo

Comment: @riov8 maybe in another position

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this comment

Comment: I want to express that it is possible to jump to the location of another file, which is not necessarily in the node_modules directory, likes markdown file

Comment: and you want this in your doxygen html files or as a feature of VSC

Comment: Thank you for reply, finaly, I used markdown file to achieved it.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70224273/11107541